# Combine two custom taxonomy terms into one in Wordpress (complex math needed?)

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a fairly simple problem that I can't seem to find a fix for, and I can't seem to find anything like the question after 4 hours of research here.

Basically, my website is a movie website and I have a custom taxonomy called "mood", which has terms like "cute" & "easy" & "thought-provoking", etc. What I want to do is create an archive template that will display posts that are "cute and easy", "cute and thought-provoking", "easy and thought-provoking", etc.

It seems like a math problem to get all the right combinations but I don't even know how I can approach this from a PHP perspective. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$custom_terms = get_terms('mood');
 $custom_terms2 = get_terms('mood');
foreach(array($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
foreach(array($custom_terms2 as $custom_term2) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $custom_term->slug
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $custom_term2->slug
    ),

)

     );

   }} ?>
```

As you can tell this works as well as a Moroccan administrative procedure (trust me, I'm from there).

I have plugins to do this with ajax but none that will allow me to have a template (which I need to customize for SEO considerations).

Help? Thank you!!